# Time & work concept question

Tags: contest-math

If 3 men or 5 women can finish a work in 43 days. Then in how many days 5 men and 6 women together do it ?

Comment: Please show your effort in solving this problem so that you can be helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time and Work in Unitary Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588114/time-and-work-in-unitary-method)

Comment: aditiya jain its not the same question .. i think you did not read the question properly.

Comment: @RaviKadyan It is the same question and more of a hint than you deserve. If you would do your own work you might actually see that,

Comment: my question contain or not and that make a huge difference

Comment: 215 days! Because one woman is working and you can guess what the rest of the crew is doing!

Comment: @denklo Read the question again  "3 men OR 5 women can finish a work in 43 days"

Comment: Mark the answer which is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the answer..

$3M=5W$

$1M=5/3W$

Then Formula of this $(Man1 * days * hours)/work=(man2 * days * hours )/work$

$5(5/3) + 6 +D = 5* 43$

$D=15$

Comment: it is just a short trick. it doesn't make sense to downvote.

Comment: You have to give support instead of downvote. if you have a better answer post it. ask question raiser to mark as answer.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, be sure ! I was just trying to make a joke. I upvote your answer and delete my comment since, obviously, you took it badly. This was not my intent. So, I really apologize. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnDouma. I was just trying to make a joke ! Comment deleted

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici Now it is alright, my mean was not like I took it badly. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A man does $\frac{1}{3\times 43} = \frac1{129}$th  of the job in one day, whereas a woman does $\frac{1}{5\times 43} = \frac{1}{215}$th of the job.

Working together, $5$ men and $6$ women do 
$$\frac{5}{129}+\frac{6}{215}=\frac{1}{15}\text{th}$$
of the job.  Thus they require 15 days.

Answer (score 1):

If $3$ men can finish a work in $43$ days, then $1$ man can finish a work in $43\times3=129$ days. so a man can finish $\frac{1}{129}$ of a work in a day.

If $5$ women can finish a work in $43$ days, then $1$ woman can finish a work in $43\times5=215$ days, so a woman can finish $\frac{1}{215}$ of a work in a day.

So, 5 men and 6 women can finish $\frac{1}{129}\times5+\frac{1}{215}\times6=\frac{1}{15}$ work in a day, so it requires $15$ days to finish the work with 5 men and 6 women.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $a$ be the amount done by a man in one day and $b$ be the amount done by a woman in one day.  Then if there are $d$ days and $m$ men and $w$ women, the total amount done $T$ 
is presumably $$T=d \left(am+bw\right)$$

You can calculate

- the value for $a$ when $T=1, d=43, m=3, w=0$
- the value for $b$ when $T=1, d=43, m=0, w=5$

and (assuming they do not change) use these to find

- the value for $d$ when $T=1, m=5, w=6$